# Angular Amplify Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. The configuration object is missing required auth properties

Tags: angular, yaml, github-actions, aws-amplify

I have changed nothing in regards to how my auth is setup, how amplify is setup or how my github actions script deploys.

Today on a standard deployment to Dev I received no errors in the deployment but now when I try to access my site I get the following in the console:

```
43:57.63 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
            The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
            This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

        1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
            See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

        2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

Everything that I have setup works locally which leads me to believe something is messed up with the old way of initializing Amplify via my deployment script.

I have included the relevant piece of code below: (Github  Actions)

```
  cd angular-master
  npm install @aws-amplify/cli -g
  npm install @aws-amplify/core -g
  npm install --legacy-peer-deps
  amplify init --amplify "{\"envName\":\"dev\"}" --categories "{\"auth\":{\"userPoolId\": \"${{ secrets.DEV_USER_POOL_ID }}\",\"identityPoolId\": \"${{ secrets.DEV_IDENTITY_POOL_ID }}\",\"webClientId\": \"${{ secrets.DEV_WEB_CLIENT }}\",\"nativeClientId\": \"${{ secrets.DEV_NATIVE_CLIENT }}\" }}" --yes
  node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c dev
  docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
  docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
  echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your aws config file in the deployment and the file contains the proper credentials?

Comment: Yes -- everything is exactly as it was when this setup worked end to end.

Comment: Actually isn't the difference that locally you have the .aws credentials installed on your environment? The key client/key secret?